# How to programmatically add a search bar to a UITableView header?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, uiviewanimation

How would i go about programmatically adding a search bar into a uitableview header? Specifically i have a bar button item that when it's pressed i would like to animate in a search bar into the table view header and when the cancel button is pressed it will animate back out of the view and the header scales back to normal. Would this be possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's based on **Swift 2** but It's not very diff to swift 3

Add search delegate to view controller:

```
UISearchResultsUpdating
```

Make a search:

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
```

Set this default values for searchController:

```
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
definesPresentationContext = true
```

Add search to table:

```
table.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

This delegate let you know start searching:

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    filterContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text!)
}
```

Impliment your search function:

```
func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    // do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Setup the Search Bar programatically

First add **UISearchBarDelegate** to your class

```
let searchBar = UISearchBar()
searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 70)
searchBar.delegate = self
searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.default
searchBar.placeholder = " Search Here....."
searchBar.sizeToFit()
```

and add the search bar to UITableView header

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar
```