# Search Bar Animation Override

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am in the middle of implementing search into a tableView based app. I have currently implemented it using a UIView in Storyboard (which I have placed in the [tableHeaderView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614904-tableheaderview)) with the following code:

```
    resultsTableController = SearchResultsTableViewController()
    resultsTableController.tableView.delegate = self
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsTableController)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

    tableViewSearchBarView.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
```

I am currently getting this jerky animation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rsex4.jpg

Can I create a custom animation that will happen when the search bar is clicked and cancelled and override this animation somehow? I can't use the normal:

```
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

as I need to have the Title in a custom tableHeaderView and not in a navigationBar.

How could I go about doing this? I am just wanting a normal animation like what is in the stock Apple Notes App.

Comment: Here is the solution of your question -> https://blog.kiprosh.com/ios-11-new-navigation-bar-and-search-controller/. Still have any issue then ask.

Comment: @dahiya_boy This is using the navigationBar and not a custom tableViewHeader. This is a different answer.

Comment: Apple notes app have searchcontroller in NavBar not in TableView Header. Moreover, if you wanted to searchController in tableView then you can go with this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42200140/how-to-programmatically-add-a-search-bar-to-a-uitableview-header